# What is assisted GPS?

Tags: gps

[This site](http://www.droidthing.com/device/samsung-i9000-galaxy-s-29) describes the Galaxy as having "Assisted GPS". What does this mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Assisted GPS is a system which can improve the startup performance of a GPS satellite-based positioning system.

[Wikipedia has your best answer.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS)

Comment: More specifically, it uses the cell network so that a GPS fix converges faster.

Comment: Does it need a good Cell signal to work and is there a cost to battery life

Comment: Performance will vary depending on the quality of the time signal from the cell tower and the data rate you're able to achieve.  GPS by itself is very battery intensive, but the overhead for the assisted part is fairly minimal if there's good cell coverage.

Comment: When A-GPS works, it can have significant battery life savings since it lets you get a GPS fix faster and get done using the GPS faster.