# Mobile data is turned off but provider shows data trickle

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5, mobile-data, data-monitoring

I have turned off cellular data on my phone (Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1) but the data usage summary on my provider's portal is still (slowly) increasing.

Does Android still use a small amount of data even when told not to, or is it provider shenanigans?

Provider is Public Mobile.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using LTE, the reason could be, that LTE is causing traffic even if mobile data is turned off.
See here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/132642/185648

Comment: This is weird.  I have a prepaid plan and previously did not have data at all (now I do have data with the same provider), and used LTE.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to look at:

1. Does your mobile provider count standard SMS as data?
2. Does your SMS app have a setting (and is it enabled) to briefly enable mobile data when sending/receiving MMS? Ones I know that do are Handcent, ChompSMS, QKSMS, GoSMS, Textra.

Make sure the setting is off, otherwise it will briefly turn on each time you send and receive one (but note, on most carriers, you won't be able to get MMS over Wifi)

Comment: 1. Not that I know of, since I had unlimited SMS even before data, and 2. I am using hangups for SMS

Comment: Hangups or Hangouts?  I don't think Hangouts will automatically enable data for sending/receiving MMS messages, you'd have to look in the options for that.   However, limited or unlimited SMS wouldn't affect if your carrier counts it as data.