# Is it possible for any app to connect to Internet over cellular when the data connection button is off?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, data-connection

I have the following situation on an Android 5.1 phone.

(I don't think this may be a duplicate as the other similar questions I saw were about intentionally allowing or blocking apps from Cellular access.)

Because of an automatic daily-pass (they call it) charge upon any momentary connection to the Internet, I turned off the Data Connection button (from the drop-down quick menu screen) a little before the current day expired as I usually do to avoid an extra day's charge.

I was also at home next to my always-on WiFi.  This I mention because supposedly WiFi is always preferred over cellular network, right?

Hours after the button was off, I got an SMS telling me that I have connected to the Internet (cellular), and I will be charged for yet another day.  I immediately checked the Data Connection button and it was indeed off as I had left it.

So, I'm curious as to how the connection could have happened.

I want to report the company for fraud.  But, I need to be certain.

Is it possible for any application to override my manually selected Data Connection button position and use the Cellular network for data?  (And, even more so when I'm on WiFi at the moment?  But this is not the main issue.)

Now, if by any chance this is indeed possible, what would be the way to be certain my Cellular data connection is never used until I decide to do so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After complaining to the phone company, it turns out that the issue is (believe it or not) 4G related.

They refunded my unfairly charged amount, and switched me to a different data plan that excludes this daily-pass automatic connection so this won't happen again.

I have found this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/132642/223986) to another post which is correct for here also.

Answer (score 0):

Which phone is that? On some devices there is that feature called Smart Network Switch (Samsung).

Smart Network Switch is a feature  that allows your phone to automatically switch between WiFi and the mobile network. This allows the phone to maintain a high level of internet connectivity if your WiFi connection is too slow to provide a good user experience.

So in your case this may have been enabled and the phone switched to data connection when your WiFi connection was not stable.

Comment: It's not Samsung.  It's MLS (which is as good as no-name Chinese phones).  I don't think this feature is available.  How would I verify if it is?

Comment: The feature is common to Android devices, every  manufacturers name it their way. Smart Network Switch for Samsung. Depending on device but try going to Settings > Network > Wifi (options) > Smart Network Switch.

Comment: Don't see anything like it.  So, I guess this is not the case.

Comment: name and path may be different, but the feature can be found in Wifi settings. Or if there isn't, your problem is different

Comment: The only thing I see in the WiFi section that may be relevant is 'Keep WiFi on during sleep' with the options: Always, Only when plugged in (which is selected), and Never.  Incidentally, my phone was plugged in to the USB charger at the moment, so I don't think WiFi went off because of sleep, but even if so, the cellular data connection was off.  I don't think it would force data connection on rather than turn WiFi back on if it needed to connect.  And if so, what good is the data connection button if I have no final control in the matter?

Comment: On an LG G5 this setting is called "Switch to mobile data" under Settings > Network > Wi-Fi. I agree this setting (whatever it's called) is the most likely reason.

Comment: There is no such setting.  I even used the Search feature to look for any of these words separately and didn't get any relevant results.  I did find one called 'Restrict background data' with the description: "If you restrict background cellular data, some apps and services won't work unless you're connected to WiFi."  Could this be relevant?  It was not restricted.  But, if this was the culprit, then the 'Data Connection' button is practically useless -- and even worse, misleading as it lets you think you're safe when off.

Comment: I'm pretty sure network switching won't automatically turn on mobile data if it was turned off: it only applies when both mobile data and Wi-Fi are enabled.