# I cannot find my current location while offline in google maps

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

Before I could easily find my current location being offline using offline maps but at present in the updated Google maps I am not able to use it. It shows the location while I am online, and once I go offline the location no longer appears. What to do?

Answer (score 3):

To get a location fix while offline, GPS (not just location) needs to be enabled. You must have either "High accuracy" or "Device only" enabled under Settings->Location->Mode. "Battery saving" does not allow use of GPS.

When you are offline, the time to get a location fix is much higher than when you are online.

There are two reasons for this:

1. WiFi based location is very fast. Without being online, you cannot use WiFi location.
2. GPS works much faster when you are online, due to the benefits of [Assisted GPS](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1522/100457). Without Assisted GPS, your GPS receiver needs to do a search for satellites itself which can take a few minutes. GPS also requires sufficient visibility to satellites, so don't try to use GPS while underground or in so-called urban canyons with lots of skyscrapers blocking the sky.

---

Summary: make sure GPS is on and wait a few minutes in an outdoor space where you can see the sky. Your location should appear.